# Prepopulate dropdown list by value

Tags: json, docusignapi

I need to prepopulate a dropdown on an envelope that contains marital statuses.
I use the following JSON through the REST API:

```
{
   "templateRoles":[
      {
         "email":"a1c4325f-c94c-489a-b15a-60e79b109af0@dsp.kryptiq.com",
         "name":"George Washington",
         "roleName":"Patient",
         "recipientId":1,
         "clientUserId":"1",
         "tabs":{
            "listTabs":[
               {
                  "tabLabel":"\\*MaritalStatus",
                  "value":"M"
               },
            ],
         }
      },
      {
         "email":"1967b78f-6841-4875-9467-da27c5d964e6@dsp.kryptiq.com",
         "name":"Harry Winston",
         "roleName":"Provider",
         "recipientId":2,
         "clientUserId":"2"
      }
   ],
   "templateId":"35d20780-e451-4935-8ead-3984d86c5de5",
   "status":"sent"
}
```

This works when the template was set up with the dropdown items as:
M;S;D;W

and the dropdown values are blank

But when I set the dropdown items to be:
Married;Single;Divorced;Widowed

and the dropdown values to be:
M;S;D;W

The prepopulation no longer works.

The "value" field seems to map to the items on the dropdown list.  Is it possible to prepopulate a dropdown list using the value (key)?

Comment: I am able to repro the behavior you describe, and this seems like a REST API bug to me.  If you edit the "Drop Down Tag Properties" in the Template itself to set "Selected Value" to "M", this will cause "Married" to be pre-selected for the signer during the signing session -- there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to do things the same way with the REST API (i.e., set value = "M" in the REST API Create Envelope request to cause the selected value to be "Married" during the signing session).

Answer (score 0):

I too am seeing the same thing, and I agree that this is most likely a bug in the REST API.  I will log a bug for this.  In the mean time, it seems to work if you simply use the items list instead of the values list, so I'm wondering if you can use that as a workaround and map to specific "values" on your side once you have the selection.

As you have found out, you can pre-populate your drop down if you save the template with ITEMS set to `Married;Single;Divorced;Widowed` and no VALUES set, then in your API call you call with:

```
"listTabs":[
    {
        "tabLabel":"MaritalStatus",
        "value":"Married"
    }
]
```

And it starts out with the first selection (Married) selected.  If you the signer then selects a drop down item, completes the signing, then downloads the form data for that completed envelope, they will get back "Married" as a value.  Your code can then map that to anything on your side (i.e. you have table mapping of 1;2;3;4 for Married;Single;Divorced;Widowed or M;S;D;W, etc.)